# Get List of dates from object

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Ive read a few threads and not sure how to get the earliest and the latest date from a range.

Example of data (most columns skipped for brevity)

```
CustID StartDate   EndDate
1       01/01/2015  01/01/2015
2       03/01/2015  03/01/2015
3       03/01/2015  05/01/2015
4       03/01/2015  10/01/2015
```

The UI allows the user to select a date from a calendar control. It should then  get all the dates that fall within the range above, so if a user selects

02/01/2015 - nothing is returned as no `startDate` or `EndDate` match this date/range

If they select 01/01/2015 then i would expect to to get the following dates

```
01/01/2015
03/01/2015
04/01/2015
05/01/2015
.... to 10/01/2015
```

Notice the date **02/01/2015 is NOT** included.

If the user selects 03/01/2015 then it will return all the dates up until 10/01/2015.

To achieve this i wrote the code

```
public List<DateTime> GetDates()
{

    IEnumerable<Customers> Dates = dc.Customers.Where(d => d.StartDate.Value >= DateTime.Now );

    DateTime FromDate = Dates.Where(f => f.StartDate.HasValue).Min(f => f.StartDate).Value;
    DateTime ToDate = Dates.Where(t => t.EndDate.HasValue).Max(f => f.EndDate).Value;

    IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDates = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                 .Select(x => FromDate.Date.AddDays(x))
                 .TakeWhile(x => x <= ToDate.Date);

    return AllDates.ToList();
}
```

but its not returning the dates i expected. With this code if i select 01/01/2015, it returns all the dates? Where am i going wrong?

Comment: are your dates formatted dd/MM/yy?

Comment: what if you changed `.TakeWhile(x => x <= ToDate.Date);` to 
`.TakeWhile(x => x = ToDate.Date);`

Comment: Dates are not formatted. Im using the Date type. @MethodMan i gave that a try and that didnt work

Comment: I am totally confused by your entire post.  when you say "get all the dates that fall within the range above" what do you mean?  Do you mean get all the start dates and end dates that are greater than the user selected date?

Comment: He wants all the dates in all ranges that starts after the selected date.

Comment: I don't completely understand the question, but it's worth noting that you CAN use <, >, =, >=, and <= when comparing dates. It would probably make the problem a lot easier to look at and conceptualize.

Comment: Did the example i provided make sense? Its a bit like a calendar, select a couple dates with a meeting and you want these to show up not anything else??

Comment: So he wants the union of (1/1/2015 - 1/1/2015)(03/01/2015 - 03/01/2015)(       03/01/2015  - 05/01/2015)(03/01/2015 - 10/01/2015) I think

Comment: @RobertMcKee - you mean the startdates and enddates of all the records where startdate is >= to the user selected date (assuming enddate is always greater than startdate for any record)

Comment: computer - no, the examples do not help.  You mention a user selected date, but the code never seems to check against that.  The code does check against Datetime.Now, but that is never mentioned in your explanation.  From what you say that 2/1/2015 should not give you anything, i think that you want ranges that include the user selected date, but then you say that 1/1/2015 should give you dates like 5/1/2015 but the range that has that date (for customer 3) does not include 1/1/2015.  What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Would have been great for whoever decided to mark down my question to give a reason,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that he's trying to populate a calendar control with dates that have already been selected by other customers, so the user can't select them, but he's trying to reduce the number of items returned to a smaller set.  Of course the example data would be wrong then as it already has overlapping dates, so...

First pass:

```
public List<DateTime> GetDates()
{

    IEnumerable<Customers> Dates = dc.Customers
      .Where(d => d.StartDate.Value >= DateTime.Now);

    var FromDate = Dates.Where(f => f.StartDate.HasValue)
      .Min(f => f.StartDate).Value;
    var ToDate = Dates.Where(t => t.EndDate.HasValue)
      .Max(f => f.EndDate).Value;


    IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDates = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
                 .Select(x => FromDate.Date.AddDays(x))
                 .TakeWhile(x => x <= ToDate.Date)
                 .Where(x=>dc.Customers.Any(c=>x>=c.StartDate && x<=c.EndDate));

    return AllDates.ToList();
}
```

This is a better solution, but returns all dates in all ranges, further reduce by adding a where clause where you need to.  Put it before the `.ToList` if you really want to exclude all the ranges that don't have a startdate >= your selection, or put it at the end if you actually want to to include them, but not return the portion that is < your selection (more likely).

```
public List<DateTime> GetDates()
{
    return db.Customers
      .ToList()
      .Select(pair =>
             Enumerable.Range(0,(int)(pair.EndDate - pair.StartDate).TotalDays+1)
                       .Select(days => pair.StartDate.AddDays(days)))
      .SelectMany(x=>x)
      .Distinct();
}
```

Bonus:

```
/* DateTime extension for ranges of dates */
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> EnumerableTo(this DateTime self, DateTime toDate)
    {
        for(var d=self;d<=toDate;d=d.Date.AddDays(1))
           yield return d;
    }
}
void Main()
{
    /* Your example data */
    var Customers=new [] {
      new { id=1,StartDate=new DateTime(2015,1,1),EndDate=new DateTime(2015,1,1)},
      new { id=2,StartDate=new DateTime(2015,1,3),EndDate=new DateTime(2015,1,3)},
      new { id=3,StartDate=new DateTime(2015,1,3),EndDate=new DateTime(2015,1,5)},
      new { id=4,StartDate=new DateTime(2015,1,3),EndDate=new DateTime(2015,1,10)},
    };

    /* The query */
    var results=Customers
       .Select(pair => pair.StartDate.EnumerableTo(pair.EndDate))
       .SelectMany(x=>x)
       .Distinct();

    results.Dump();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a union of start dates and end dates for all customers where the startdate is greater than the user selected date, then why not something like

```
return (from costumer in dc.Customers select costumer.startdate
           where costumer.startdate > UserSelectedDate)
   .Union
       (from costumer in dc.Customers select costumer.enddate
           where costumer.startdate > UserSelectedDate)
   .Distinct()
```

if what you want, instead, is all the start dates and end dates where the user selected falls within that range, then you would do

```
return (from costumer in dc.Customers select costumer.startdate
           where costumer.startdate <= UserSelectedDate and
                 UserSelectedDate <= costumer.enddate)
   .Union
       (from costumer in dc.Customers select costumer.enddate
           where costumer.startdate <= UserSelectedDate and
                 UserSelectedDate <= costumer.enddate)
   .Distinct()
```